# Is it possible to pass values by reference from Python to C++ via Cython?

Tags: python, c++, cython

Is it possible to create a C++ object that contains a pointer to a Python variable? My concern is that the Python variable is a PyObject and thus there is no way that C++ could read it properly.

To make an example, here is the tutorial from the official [Cython website](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html) slightly altered for my question. The results from main.py are wrong

**Main.py (where the Rectangle object is used)**

```
import rect
x0, y0, x1, y1 = 1, 2, 3, 4
rect_obj = rect.PyRectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1)
print(rect_obj.get_area())

x0 = 10                       # change value PyRectangle points to
print(rect_obj.get_area())
```

**Result**

```
-403575482
-407128282
```

**Rectangle.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Rectangle.h"

namespace shapes {

    // Overloaded constructor
    Rectangle::Rectangle (int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1) {
        this->x0 = &x0;
        this->y0 = y0;
        this->x1 = x1;
        this->y1 = y1;
    }

    // Return the area of the rectangle
    int Rectangle::getArea () {
        return (this->x1 - *(this->x0)) * (this->y1 - this->y0);
    }
}
```

For the sake of clarity, I did not post the other files as I do not think they are necessary for understanding my question.

Comment: The pointer you acquire with `&x0` becomes invalid as soon as the constructor returns, since it's the address of an argument.

Comment: Makes sense. Guess I'm too used to Python.

Comment: This wouldn't work in Python either; assigning to `x0` has no effect on anything but that variable.

Comment: Well it depends on what you pass to the object. In this case you're right. After doing some research, I can't find a solution for my problem. Therefore I will declare and define x0 in C++ as well and write a function to change it with Python. Thanks for your help!

Comment: "thus there is no way that C++ could read it properly" - there is the Python C API for exactly this purpose. Python integers are immutable though (and often "singletons" too).

Answer (score 0):

On performing some experiments I found a solution, where you have to explicitly call the ***cinit*** method that you have defined in the **.pyx** file.

The new python file would look something like this

```
import rect
x0, y0, x1, y1 = 1, 2, 3, 4 \
rect_obj = rect.PyRectangle() \
rect_obj._cinit_(x0, y0, x1, y1) \
print(rect_obj.get_size()) \
print(rect_obj.get_area())
```

and your **.pyx** looks as this

```
from Rectangle cimport Rectangle

cdef class PyRectangle:
    cdef Rectangle c_rect

def _cinit_(self, int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1):
    self.c_rect = Rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1)

def get_area(self):
    return self.c_rect.getArea()

def get_size(self):
    cdef int width, height
    self.c_rect.getSize(&width, &height)
    return width, height

def move (self, dx, dy):
    self.c_rect.move(dx, dy)
```